Where are Excel Power Query queries recorded in Excel file?
Out of curiosity, where are Power Query M 'scripts' recorded in Excel file? I unzipped an Excel file containing a PQ query but couldn't locate it in expanded file.
I am also asking this question as it can get tricky to change table column names all the way down from Excel tables, Power Query, Data Model and DAX, and subsequent Pivot Tables. So I was naïvely trying to locate places the names appear. But I guess Power Query/M language (and Power Pivot/DAX) being proprietary and not part of Open XML Spreadsheet standard, they are hidden somehow.

They are stored as items in the customXml subfolder. However, they are stored in a compressed binary format rather than an easily readable one.
Imke Feldman has an amazing function that can decompress and extract M queries from an Excel file (or folder of Excel files) here:
https://www.thebiccountant.com/2019/03/06/bulk-extract-power-query-m-code-from-multiple-excel-files-at-once/
Edit: When I look in customXml > item1.xml, the text looks like this
<DataMashup
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/DataMashup" 
    sqmid="a2bc2952-9c3e-49e9-9405-f32f384b8e2d">
    AAAAAJsEAABQSwMEFAACAAgABGuaWA7cE7...
</DataMashup>

where the text inside the DataMashup tag is a long Base64 string chunk.

Thanks and thanks a lot for pointing the PQ function. Unfortunately, the function returns null (QueryCode = null) without error. I see in a comment that The filename where the queries reside is not known in beforehand. Just that it contains "customXml/item" and then in function body BinaryFromText = Binary.FromText(GrabText, BinaryEncoding.Base64), UnzipSection1 = fnUnzipBinary(BinaryFromText, "Formulas/Section1.m"). So query is a zip in Base64. I still can't locate any base64 string chunks in my  itemX.xml, funny xml !

Are you sure you have quries in that file? I definitely see base64 strings inside item1.xml. See my edit.

Thanks. I tried with a new Excel file (containing a simple table, simple PQ query), and indeed there is a DataMashup element in item1.xml like in your Edit. I used [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String("#text")) to extract it. I got plain XML in the middle of "garbage" characters (due to compression?). Not the "M language" code yet.  That's not the case of the previous XML for some reasons...

Searching the tag <DataMashup>, I came across this post from Ben Gribaudo (datamashupcmdlets). See also PowerShell Gallery and related posts like data-mashup-binary-stream which might be of great utility for a better understanding.
